# Compare current row and the previous row in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a dataset containing a tag for each row.
I want to calculate the number of rows which its tag is "Tag1" and its previous row's tag is "Tag2"

I wrote this code, but it throws "string indices must be integers" error.

```
    counter = 0
    for index, row in train.iterrows():
        if index + 1 < train.shape[0]:
            if row['tag'] == "Tag1" and row[index + 1]['tag'] == "Tag2":
                counter += 1
```

Can anyone help me to make it work or another way (maybe using shift)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `row` is a string, and not a dictionary.
You should post the actual exception you get.

Comment: it is just what train.iterrows() returns. I find it to iterate over the dataset!

Comment: If you really want to use a for loop, you can fix the code like this: ```counter = 0
for index, row in train.iterrows():
    if index + 1 < train.shape[0]:
        if row['tag'] == "Tag1" and train.iloc[index + 1]['tag'] == "Tag2":
            counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row[index + 1]['tag']` -- this is your problem. This won't access the next row. To do so you need to use

```
train['tag'][index + 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing something different than what you are describing. It checks `index+1` ad 'Tag2'. For that we can use `shift(-1)`

```
train['tag1'] = train['tag'].shift(-1)
len(train[(train['tag']=="Tag1") & (train['tag1'] =="Tag2")])
```